# Random order Elementor Section background slidshow

Tags: javascript, php, elementor

I am trying to set in the "slideshow" of Elementor section a "random" order of the slider OR a different picture each load. I cant get it to work - Can someone help ?

I have minimal knowledge in coding, and I tried different code, but without success

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+elementor+random+slideshow+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old, but I found an answer that worked for me
(If you using the new elementor containers, change the "add_action(" line to
'elementor/frontend/container/before_render')

```
    class BS_Random_Background_Slideshow_Images {

   const CONTAINER_ID = 'bg_slideshow';

   public function __construct() {
      add_action( 'elementor/frontend/section/before_render', array( $this, 'before_render' ), 10 );
   }

   function before_render( $widget ) {
      $settings = $widget->get_active_settings();

      if ( $settings['_element_id'] == self::CONTAINER_ID ) {
         $gallery = $settings['background_slideshow_gallery'];
         $rand_gallery = $this->shuffle_array( $gallery );
         $widget->set_settings( 'background_slideshow_gallery', $rand_gallery );
      }
   }

   private function shuffle_array( $array ) {
      if ( ! is_array( $array ) ) 
         return $array;

      $keys = array_keys( $array );
      shuffle( $keys );
      $random = array();
      foreach ( $keys as $key )
         $random[$key] = $array[$key];

      return array_values( $random );
   }
}
new BS_Random_Background_Slideshow_Images();
```